# Where do you put your paths in Cucumber 1.1+ for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Since the paths.env file is not generated for Cucumber 1.1+, if for example if I use the `visit login_path` frequently for my test steps, should I create an individual step for it or should I just use `visit login_path` everywhere?  If it ever changes, I can easily do a string replace under the features directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really just a matter of DRYing up your calls to `visit login_path` I'd just leave them be since they are clear and concise as they stand, and you (*probably*) ain't gonna need to change the login path helper.

However if you start seeing slightly more complicated steps like this,

```
# in features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb

When /^I go to my profile$/ do
  visit user_path(@current_user)
end
```

consider using the `paths.rb` model:

```
# in features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb

Given /^I go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end

# in features/support/paths.rb

module NavigationHelpers
  def path_to(page_name)
    when /my profile/
      user_path(@current_user)
    ...
  end
end
World(NavigationHelpers)
```

That's right, I like `paths.rb` and `selectors.rb` and copy them to new projects :)  I am glad to see the "kitchen sink" `web_steps.rb` go though.  For examples of how I use the support files: https://github.com/coshx/green-eggs/blob/master/features/support

Comment: How do you know to put it in a module called "NavigationHelpers"? Is that arbitrary?

Comment: Oops, the name is arbitrary but you do have to include the module using the `World` method.  I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: That works, thanks! Found this good explanation in the docs about World() https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World